# How to reuse job in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I currently have two jobs in my CI file which are nearly identical.

The first is for manually compiling a release build from *any* git branch.

```
deploy_internal:
  stage: deploy
  script: ....<deploy code>
  when: manual
```

The second is to be used by the scheduler to release a daily build from *develop* branch.

```
scheduled_deploy_internal:
  stage: deploy
  script: ....<deploy code from deploy_internal copy/pasted>
  only: 
      variables:
          - $MY_DEPLOY_INTERNAL != null
```

This feels wrong to have all that deploy code repeated in two places. It gets worse. There are also deploy_external, deploy_release, and scheduled variants.

My question:
Is there a way that I can combine `deploy_internal` and `scheduled_deploy_internal` such that the manual/scheduled behaviour is retained (DRY basically)?

Alternatively: Is there is a better way that I should structure my jobs?

Edit:
Original title: Deploy job. Execute manually except when scheduled

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use YAML anchors and aliases to reuse the script.

```
deploy_internal:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - &deployment_scripts |
      echo "Deployment Started"
      bash command 1
      bash command 2
  when: manual

scheduled_deploy_internal:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - *deployment_scripts
  only:
    variables:
      - $MY_DEPLOY_INTERNAL != null
```

Or you can use [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) keyword.

```
.deployment_script:
  script:
    - echo "Deployment started"
    - bash command 1
    - bash command 2

deploy_internal:
  extends: .deployment_script
  stage: deploy
  when: manual

scheduled_deploy_internal:
  extends: .deployment_script
  stage: deploy
  only:
    variables:
      - $MY_DEPLOY_INTERNAL != null
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was wanting.

Comment: Nice I knew you could use anchors like 
```validate:
  <<: *buildImage
```
but not within `scripts:`

Answer (score 2):

Use [GitLab's `default` section containing a `before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-default-configuration-from-an-included-configuration-file):

```yaml
default:
  before_script:
    - ....<deploy code>

job1:
  stage: deploy
  script: ....<code after than deploy>

job2:
  stage: deploy
  script: ....<code after than deploy>
```

> Note: the `default` section fails to function as such if you try to execute a job locally with the `gitlab-runner exec` command - use [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-variables) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden job in template file that you can extend after that in multiple jobs. (This solution was already mentioned in this thread)

```
#template.yml
.wget-job:
  stage: download
  image: alpine/wget
  variables:
    URL_TO_GET: ""
    WGET_OPTS: ""
  script:
    - |
      #! /bin/sh
      wget $WGET_OPTS $URL_TO_GET


#.gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  file:
    - template.yml

stages:
  - download

download-1:
  extends: .wget-job
  variables:
    URL_TO_GET: "https://fake.url.com/file"

download-2:
  extends: .wget-job
  variables:
    URL_TO_GET: "https://fake.url.com/file2"
```